# In an iOS renderer is it necessary to check if an object is the object I think it is (in this case a UITabBarController?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this renderer an iOS renderer and I would like to try and understand something about this code. Specifically at this point:

```
    try
    {
        var tabbarController = (UITabBarController)this.ViewController;

        if (null != tabbarController)
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.PropertyChanged += Current_PropertyChanged; 
            tabbarController.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;
            UpdateTheme();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what would be the benefit of doing all these checks. For example.  Why would this need to be inside a "try" and why would I need to do the check "if (null != tabbarController)".  I am all for making code safe but these seem too much. Am I correct or should I leave these checks in?

For reference, here's the full renderer code:

```
public class TabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
{
    private MainPage _page;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            _page = (MainPage)e.NewElement;
        }
        else
        {
            _page = (MainPage)e.OldElement;
        }

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.PropertyChanged -= Current_PropertyChanged;
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var tabbarController = (UITabBarController)this.ViewController;

            if (null != tabbarController)
            {
                Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.PropertyChanged += Current_PropertyChanged; 
                tabbarController.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;
                UpdateTheme();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception);
        }
    }


    private void OnTabbarControllerItemSelected(object sender, UITabBarSelectionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (!(_page.CurrentPage is Japanese.CardsTabPage) && App.quizRunning == true)
        {
            _page.CurrentPage = App.navCardsTabPage;
        }
    }

    void Current_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "DarkTheme")
            UpdateTheme();
    }

    void UpdateTheme()
    {
        var isDarkTheme = (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current as App).DarkTheme;

        if (isDarkTheme)
            TabBar.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.White;
        else
            TabBar.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.Red;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me what would be the benefit of doing all these checks?

I will try to be as helpful as possible in brief.

> Why would this need to be inside a "try"

Well, Try-catch blocks are usually used in areas where the programmer thinks there are the most chances of some or the other exception to be thrown which if not handled may cause a crash(You do not want your app to crash now do you).

> why would I need to do the check "if (null != tabbarController)"

This one is quite simple actually there might be points in your code lifecycle where there could be chances that the PageRenderer's ViewController property to be null and in that case if your code reaches `tabbarController.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;` What do you think would happen?

I say your app goes **BOOM** (if you ignore the try catch that is.). Of course, you could just do `tabbarController?.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;` instead as of `C#` 6 but in the end, the point is you will execute unneeded lines of code here.

**Update** I was in soo much hurry that I didn't even notice that the line of code was an assignment and hence you cannot do `tabbarController?.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;` since the '?' cannot appear in the left side of an assignment. Thank you **@apineda** for pointing it out.

> I am all for making code safe but these seem too much. Am I correct or should I leave these checks in?

I would suggest you leave these checks I do not personally think there is any unneeded piece of code in there.

**NOTE: These are my personal views other people might differ.**

Good luck feel free to revert in case of queries.

Comment: Just one small comment, the C# null operator does not work with assignments. This is why `tabbarController?.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;` would not be possible to do.

Comment: @apineda Oh lol yeah, I didn't even notice I did that! Thanks, man.